# Post downvoted based on misunderstanding

Tags: discussion, downvotes, specific-answer

A person downvoted an answer with improper understanding of Java basic concepts. He added his [comments for downvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423622/volatile-vs-static-in-java/37114038#comment96417719_37114038), which are invalid:

> volatile: This keyword is applicable to both class and instance variables. The statement you said above is incorrect regarding applicable to class. only two key words that applicable to variable is volatile and transient. so volatile wont applicable for class. – ASR

But `volatile` keyword is applicable for static (class) variables.

How to handle this scenario?

<sub>It's not about losing two points but that the answer was downvoted for wrong reasons.</sub>

Comment: Take a deep breath and move on. You can't control the actions or beliefs of other people.

Comment: That comment did not mention downvoting, in its current state nor in its edit history.  Downvoting is anonymous; don't assume you know who downvoted you.

Comment: You can respond to the comment and clarify the user's misunderstanding. You can also edit your answer to clear the misunderstanding, for the benefit of anyone else who would come to the site with the same misunderstanding. Notice that in none of these scenarios do you address 'the downvote'. Cause you don't do it. The important part is the misunderstanding, not the button the user pressed on your post :)

Answer (score 12):

Downvotes are for "this answer is not useful".

You provided an answer to very complicated topic that already has a lot of coverage on SO and outside. Presumably you've done it because you personally found that this exact way of explaining the topic *useful*. There are some people who found it useful too, but you request that everyone finds your particular explanation useful. This is not how people work - we all have different ways to learn about things and some need pictures, some need deep details and some need summary explanation.

I personally find your answer "not useful" because significant portion is already covered in older answer and your post does not talk about [Is a write to a volatile a memory-barrier in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688697/is-a-write-to-a-volatile-a-memory-barrier-in-java). I would likely downvote your answer if someone would point me to your answer as "*the bestest and the mostest usefulest* on whole planet".

Side note: if you want to discuss whether author of the comment who possibly read "applicable to both class and instance variables" as "applicable to class as well as applicable to instance variables" instead of intended "applicable to class variables and instance variables" is wrong then https://english.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place. I'd simply rewrite it as "... static and instance variables" to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 6):

Why are you complaining? Voting is anonymous, and yet that person added a negative comment to your post, and probably downvoted it at the same time, which is kind of brave and transparent (even if anonymous downvotes are the standard, fortunately).

Would you prefer an anonymous downvote for the wrong reasons (that you don't know)?

Note that another scenario could be: someone shares your link to several people, one gives negative feedback, and the other reads the feedback and downvotes.

At least you know almost for sure *why* your post was downvoted, and that gives you a chance to discuss with the person that probably did it, maybe edit your post, and make them change their mind, reverse their downvote, or - if it's not them - counter the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

> How to handle this scenario?

You have nothing to handle. You have simply received a vote on one of your answer, so simply move on.

Will you complain when you get an upvote on a wrong answer?<sup>1</sup> I don't think so.

Don't forget that someone [may have lost their keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/386331).

<sup>1: yes I saw upvotes on wrong answer but I may be wrong.</sup>

Comment: Tim's answer is a joke. It's not meant to discourage people from taking feedback into account.

Comment: @CodyGray yes but *the joke* means for me that we may have downvotes for various reasons that we cannot know. He also said : `It's one down vote, don't worry about it - as long as you're sure that your answer is good, then put it out of mind`. So having a +5/-1 doesn't really mean we should do something or we should worry about. If it was +5/-4 then probably there is something to consider.

Comment: Yes, one possible way of taking feedback into account is by ignoring it. If you are completely confident that your answer is correct and helpful, and you don't see any way that you can improve it, then feel free to ignore the downvote. Or ignore 10 downvotes. In this case, though, there is an indication in the comments that someone was confused about the meaning of the volatile keyword, so arguably the answer could be made *better* by addressing that confusion directly in the answer. It won't necessarily make the downvote go away, but it makes the answer better.