# Is "avoid downvoting because your own misunderstandings" a rule?

Tags: discussion

I got a comment: "And please avoid downvoting because your own misunderstandings, that is opposite of the StackOverflow voting rules." (related to an answer vote)

Naturally I don't think there is a rule like that (especially with [lost the keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397) reason). I believe one should vote when they feel they are misunderstanding question or answer due to the fact it is unclear...

So is there such a rule?

---

<sub>PS that is not duplicate of my own answer to [Post downvoted based on misunderstanding](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380551/post-downvoted-based-on-misunderstanding) because that could be my misunderstanding of the rules.</sub>

<sub>PPS image of comments so no one goes hunting for the post (as spoiler), and yes, I know that I should not have downvoted and commented on the same post:</sub>

> [image]

Comment: FYI: That comment got auto-flagged by the rude comments bot. In response to the flag, I removed the sentence you're referring to, which was rude, wrong, and irrelevant.

Comment: @CodyGray I didn't find that part to be rude, I can see "irrelevant"...  but I bet my comments get some of those flags too so not going to judge bot on it :)

Comment: If you misunderstand an answer (and I'm not saying you did), then by definition it is not useful.

Comment: I regularly disagree with the bot. This wasn't one of those times. Attempting to dictate how people vote is a pretty clear line for me.

Comment: The comment is self-inconsistent anyway.  If you avoid downvoting because you misunderstand something, then you must have understood that you misunderstood something,  so you would actually end up understanding and so not downvoting because of misunderstandings.  Surely that's clear?

Comment: Too many users of this site don't know better. I'm not sure whether we need more Meta questions like these or one FAQ to rule them all.

Comment: @MartinJames I think that, if I'm not misunderstanding (?), the user is saying that if you are unsure you shouldn't vote.

Comment: @Braiam Did you misunderstand what Martin James said? ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no such rule. We do not police how you use your votes, except for the following scenarios:

- revenge downvoting (targeting a user with multiple downvotes)
- targeted upvoting (targeting a user with multiple upvotes)

Other than these two scenarios, users can vote as they please for any other reasons or whims.

Comment: Even if the weather is bad? :)

Comment: @machine_1 yes, I upvoted your comment just now because it is too sunny where I am.